# JavaScript Date Bug February 2014

Tags: javascript, date

So I have this JS-code:

```
var d1 = new Date();
d1.setFullYear(2014);
d1.setMonth(1);
d1.setDate(1);
```

Should be Feb-01-2014, right? Only it's not... It returns Mar-01-2014 (actually, the full value is "Sat Mar 01 2014 20:54:29 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)"). What the hell? Same thing happens with any other date value.

If I use this code, however, it works fine:

`var d1 = new Date(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);`

The result is: Sat Feb 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what's happening, line for line:

You create a new date object with today's date.

```
var d1 = new Date(); // d1 = 2014-04-30
```

Then you set the year to 2014, which it already is, so nothing really happens.

```
d1.setFullYear(2014); // d1 = 2014-04-30
```

Here's the tricky part, because now you change the month to February. But this would make the date February the 30th (`2014-02-30`) which doesn't exist, so the JavaScript will try to find the closest valid date which is first of March (`2014-03-01`).

```
d1.setMonth(1); // d1 = 2014-02-30 is not valid so JS makes it 2014-03-01
```

Then you set the day to the first day of the month, which it already is, so nothing really happens here either.

```
d1.setDate(1) // d1 = 2014-03-01
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who responded! I see now what I did wrong... Problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

You need to call setDate first. Basically it's grabbing the month and using the current date and since February doesn't have a 30th, it's defaulting to March.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
d1.setFullYear(2014);
d1.setDate(1);
d1.setMonth(1);
```

What you were doing:

```
d1.setFullYear(2014);  // change year to 2014 (30 Apr 2014 -> 30 Apr 2014)
d1.setMonth(1);        // change month to 1 (30 Apr 2014 -> 30 Feb 2014, really 2 Mar 2014)
d1.setDate(1);         // change day of month to 1 (2 Mar 2014 -> 1 Mar 2014)
```

By setting the date first, you're changing the date to 1 Apr 2014 before changing the month.

Answer (score 0):

Better to initialize Date, rather than have it default to the current date.

```
var d1 = new Date(0); // 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC
```