# Wrong Javascript Month After 2020

Tags: javascript, date

Can anyone tell me why the month is March instead of Feb, if I enter a year after 2020?
Tested on Windows 10, Chrome & Edge

```
  const date = new Date()
  date.setFullYear("2021")
  date.setMonth("1") // February
  date.setDate("23")
  console.log(date)
```

The result of console log...

> Tue Mar 23 2021 22:38:13 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)

The following shows the correct month though...

```
var event = new Date('August 19, 2025 23:15:30');
event.setMonth(1);
console.log(event);
```

Result is

> Wed Feb 19 2025 23:15:30 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)

**Please Note:** If I use year **2020 or below**, the return values are correct. The answer needs to explain this anamoly...

Comment: my date is 23rd, not 29th, but strangely, setting the date first works...

if you submit answer I can mark it as answered

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Date Bug February 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23395934/javascript-date-bug-february-2014)

Comment: It does not explain why it works for year 2020

Comment: 2020 is a leap year, it has 29th of February. (I assume you are testing this code today, 29th of July)

Comment: Crikey, set it all in one go: `d.setFullYear(2021, 1, 23)`. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to extend the comment ("*2020 is a leap year, it has 29th of February. (I assume you are testing this code today, 29th of July)*") with example code:

```js
function test29(year){
  var date=new Date();
  date.setDate(29); // "emulate" today, 29th of something
  
  date.setFullYear(year);
  date.setMonth(1);
  date.setDate(23);
  console.log(date);
}
console.log("test29 is affected by leap years:");
test29(2019);
test29(2020);
test29(2021);
function test19(year){
  var date=new Date();
  date.setDate(19); // "emulate" a 19th of something
  
  date.setFullYear(year);
  date.setMonth(1);
  date.setDate(23);
  console.log(date);
}
console.log("test19 is not affected by leap years:");
test19(2019);
test19(2020);
test19(2021);
```

Plus what the pointed duplicate ([JavaScript Date Bug February 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23395934/javascript-date-bug-february-2014)) writes.